# Apache apisix : failed to fetch data from etcd

Tags: docker, etcd, apache-apisix

I'm using `apisix` in container mode in my local machine and I can't get to set routes using the config file, I read the logs and It turned out that the error is fetching data from `etcd`.

logs :

```
2023-04-29 16:55:07 2023/04/29 16:55:07 [error] 48#48:
 *108 [lua] config_etcd.lua:634: failed to fetch data from etcd: 
 http://etcd:2379: Service Unavailable,  
 etcd key: /apisix/upstreams, context: ngx.timer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error stated: `http://etcd:2379: Service Unavailable,`. You should check if `apisix` container can connect to the `etcd` service.

Usually, this error means your `apisix` contain and `etcd` are not in the same network. I suggest you start with the latest document: https://docs.api7.ai/apisix